# Clave de matriz no definida "id" en insertar.php en la línea 6

Tags: php, html

El código funcionaba bien, pero ahora que realicé unos cambios en el abm, me da error en el id, la verdad no entiendo que es el error.

El error que me da es clave de matriz no definida "id" en `C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\articulos\insertar.php` en la línea 6

```php
    <?php
    include("conexion.php");
    $conn=conectar();
    
    
    $id=$_GET['id']; // <-- aqui me salta el error
    $cod_art=$_POST['cod_art'];
    $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
    $descrip_adic=$_POST['descrip_adic'];
    $precio=$_POST['precio'];
    
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulos ( `cod_art`, `id`, `descripcion`, `descrip_adic`, `precio`)
        ('$cod_art', '$id','$descripcion','$descrip_adic','$precio')";
    $query= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    
    if($query){
        Header("Location: articulos.php");
        
    }else {
    }
    ?>
```

¿Podria ser que uno de los códigos no me funcionan?

Comment: Como estas mandando el 'id' en tu ruta?

Comment: Al tener `$_GET['id'];` significa que el archivo `insertar.php` requiere un parámetro `id` por url. Para llamar esa página, su url debería ser algo así: `http[s]://.../insertar.php?id=xx`

Comment: Si toda la demás data la estas recibiendo con POST, por que solo el ID seria GET ?, estas seguro que no es POST también ?

Comment: ¿Qué usas para mandar los datos al servidor, un formulario, Ajax, Fetch...? Convendría que muestres esa parte de tu código pulsando en [edit]. Además, como ya te comentan los compañeros, no deberías mezclar método (GET, POST) y usar el método específico que indicaste allí donde se recogen los datos para ser enviados.